# RegisterStartupScript and multiple controls

Tags: asp.net

I have a parentUserControl that loads a childUserControl. Multiple instances (say 3) of parentUserControl is added to the host page.

On PageLoad of the parentUserControl, I register JS:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), keyJSLoadBegin, "OnParentLoad();", true);
```

On PageLoad of hte childUserControl, I register JS:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), keyJSLoadBegin, "OnChildLoad();", true);
```

I get a JS error when I navigate to the page. The line that causes this error is (in View Source):

```
`OnParentLoad('parentA');OnChildLoad('childA');OnParentLoad('parentB');
OnParentLoad('parentC')`;OnChildLoad('childC');OnChildLoad('childB')
```

Clearly, the calls are out of order.

Anyone knows why?

**EDIT:**

The problem seems to be related to the bug here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817032

The suggestion is to register all related scripts at once. This is impossible in my situation as the scripts are in different user controls.

Has anyone come across a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The Control Model in ASP.NET intends for your code to be fully encapsulated. Each control should operate independently of the others and not depend on the load order (ideally not even depend on presence). You should rethink your approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why this happens but here is my opinion :

I think you should expose child control's scripts by a method. In parent control concatenate them in which order you want, then register your page at one place.